# Installing Slim, PHP, Ubuntu

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to install Slim on my local LAMP server on Ubuntu only I get stuck at second base.
From my tutorial and various documentation found online:

You now have access to the composer command. Sure enough if I go to
the terminal and enter:

```
$ composer
Composer version b474944155429eb4cce186c746d55287ee6bb3f4

Usage:
[options] command [arguments]
```

The next step is to specify Slim as a required package for your app.
This can be accomplished, via a composer.json file within the root of
your project.

Where is the root of my project? I thought it would be

```
/var/www/slim
```

I've tried adding composer.json to:

```
/var/www/slim
```

and stood in /slim define an index.php script with:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
echo "Hello, $name";
});
?>
```

Go to

```
http://localhost/var/www/slim
```

and the browser returns:

Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/slim/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/slim/index.php on line 2

Comment: Candidate for moving to askubuntu?

Comment: You need to run `composer install`.

Comment: Running composer install and the fatal error is fixed but browsing to localhost/slim and I get an 404 page?

Comment: You haven't defined a route for /slim, just for slim/hello. What happens if you go to localhost/slim/hello/fred? You may need a .htaccess file to rewrite all requests to index.php

Comment: You should also have a $app->run() line according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting closer me thinks. I now create a new directory on my server /var/www/myFirstSlim and stood in this; make sure composer.json is in there. Run composer install from the terminal and sure enough stuff get's installed. Although I now have to browse to http://localhost/myFirstSlimApp/vendor/slim/slim/ to load the demo index file. Thanks for the help thus far. Is this where my .htaccess comes into play? To rewrite that long URI?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there seems to be more then one question in your post, but regardless ...

1. "Where is the root of my project?"

The root of your project should be in `/var/www` if you haven't changed your hosts / Apache settings.

Then on to your 2nd question, which I will take the liberty to rephrase :)

2. "How to create your web App, and include the composer-installed packages inside?"
   go to your respective web-root directory, likely in your case `/var/www` and in it create `"index.php"`. Then, there, in the console, run the command:

   ```
   composer install
   ```

This should install the packages defined in your composer.json, which should in the same web root dir.
If everything went OO, you will have in the following a new directory: `/var/www/vendor`

Now, go to your web-root directory and create your `index.php` *and in it, in the beginning add the following lines*:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// to load all the packages installed with composer, not only slim. If 
//composer was run in the right directory and w/o problems of course :)

 $app = new \Slim\Slim();
// to instantiate Slim script instance and assign it to the pointer $app
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
echo "Hello, $name";
})
//to create your 1st route  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run

```
composer install
```

from terminal. After that, add

```
$app->run();
```

in index.php.